# What is this TouchBar button on the simulator on the new Xcode version?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10

What is this new Touchbbar button when running the Simulator from Xcode 10.2? The command like one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>⌘></kbd> on the Simulator’s Touch Bar is equivalent to the “Hardware” » “Keyboard” » “Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device”.

---

For example, let’s say your app detected <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> pressed on a physical keyboard attached to a physical device via [`keyCommands`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621141-keycommands):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        return [UIKeyCommand(input: "s", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(didPressCommandS(_:)))]
    }

    @objc func didPressCommandS(_ keyCommand: UIKeyCommand) {
        print(#function, keyCommand)
    }
}
```

Usually, though, if you press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the simulator it takes a screen snapshot. But if you turn on this “Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device” (whether through the Touch Bar or via the simulator’s menu), it will call your `UIKeyCommand` selector, just like it would on a physical device.

Comment: And what does it do?

Comment: @swiftixcode10 - It’s useful if you implement `keyCommands`. See expanded answer, above.

Comment: The most common scenario is iPad apps, because many of us have the cover with the integrated keyboard. I use the command shortcuts in iPad apps all the time. But if you’re writing apps that don’t have keyboard shortcuts, then you won’t ever need this simulator feature. But if you are writing an app with keyboard shortcuts, it’s extremely useful to be able to quickly toggle it on and off.